# Soap call takes a lot of time

Tags: php, prestashop, soap-client

I'm working on webservice dedicated to prestashop module that takes a lot of time.
The webservice return a Shipping cost on every call so if i have 4 transporters prestashop do 8 calls (4 for bloc cart and 4 for getting shippong cost on order page).
Is there any solution to reduce this time? like use using a static var.
I tried the cache but no effect because the wsdl is already on my server.

Comment: Have you set the _cache_wsdl_ option for the soap client object? you can reduce the requests by caching the responses in a file. you can first check the values in the file and if the requested value is not in the cache file execute a soap request. You also can check via soap ui what takes so much time. Is it the request because auf badly formatted xml or is it the server on the other side?

Comment: Why should i use cache_wsdl when i use it from `directory/name.wsdl` ?
I didn't tried soap ui but i have debug profiler for prestashop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must cache webservices results to improve performance:

```
        if (Cache::isStored('unique-id-for-your-module-and-request-result-' . Tools::jsonEncode($request_params)))
        {
            $shipment_options = Cache::retrieve('unique-id-for-your-module-and-request-result-' . Tools::jsonEncode($request_params));
        }
        else
        {
            $shipment_options = $api_or_soap->getEstimateCost($request_params);
            if ($shipment_options)
                Cache::store('unique-id-for-your-module-and-request-result-' . Tools::jsonEncode($request_params), $shipment_options);
        }
```

Good luck